# Is this the correct way to allocate and delete dynamic memory in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have an assignment for class, in which I need to create 3 functions to test with constant arguments. I am also supposed to create and delete dynamic memory. I have attached the exact directions from the assignment, just in case, as well as my code.

I apologize if the code is messy. I am a beginning programmer and new to the site, so I'm not exactly sure how to format everything perfectly.

Directions from assignment:

> Write a C++ program that will test three functions described below that use pointers and dynamic memory allocation.
>
> 1. Expand: takes an int array and the array's size as parameters. It should create a new array that is twice the size of the argument array. The function should copy the contents of the argument array to the new array, and initialize the unused elements of the new array with -1. The function should return a pointer to the new array.
> 2. concatenate: takes two int arrays and the arrays' sizes as parameters (that's 4 parameters). It should create a new array big enough to store both arrays. Then it should copy the contents of the first array to the new array, and then copy the contents of the second array to the new array in the remaining elements, and return a pointer to the new array.
> 3. subArray: It takes an int array, a start index and a length as arguments. It creates a new array that is a copy of the elements from the original array starting at the start index, and has length equal to the length argument. For example, subArray(aa,5,4) would return a new array containing only the elements aa[5], aa[6], aa[7], and aa[8].

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* Expand(int [], int);

int* concatenate(int[], int, int[], int);

int* subArray(int[], int, int);

int main()
{
    //Declare variables
    const int SIZEAA = 10;
    const int SIZEBB = 5;
    int aa[SIZEAA] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
    int bb[SIZEBB] = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55 };

    //Output both original arrays
    cout << "aa[10]: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZEAA; i++)
        cout << aa[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "bb[5]: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZEBB; i++)
        cout << bb[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    //Call the Expand function
    int* aaExpand = Expand(aa, SIZEAA);

    //Output expanded array
    cout << "Testing Expand: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        cout << aaExpand[i] << " ";
    //Release dynamic memory
    delete[] aaExpand;
    aaExpand = nullptr;
    cout << endl;

    //Call the concatenate function
    int* concatenateArray = concatenate(aa, SIZEAA, bb, SIZEBB);

    //Output concatenated array
    cout << "Testing concatenate: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < (SIZEAA + SIZEBB); i++)
        cout << concatenateArray[i] << " ";
    //Release dynamic memory
    delete[] concatenateArray;
    concatenateArray = nullptr;
    cout << endl;

    //Call subArray function
    int* arraySub = subArray(aa, 5, 4);

    //Output the sub array
    cout << "Testing subArray: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cout << arraySub[i] << " ";
    //Release dynamic memory
    delete[] arraySub;
    arraySub = nullptr;
    cout << endl;
}

int* Expand(int aa[], int size)     /*This function takes in an array and 
the size as parameters, creates a new array of double the size, and copies 
the old array into it.It then adds -1 into all new spaces created. 
It returns a pointer to the new array*/
{
    //Declare new array
    int* aaNew;
    int newSize = size * 2;
    aaNew = new int[newSize];

    //Copy old array into new array
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
    {
        if (i >= 0 && i < size)     //Check to see if it needs to copy an old value in or put -1 into the array
            aaNew[i] = aa[i];
        else
            aaNew[i] = -1;
    }

    return aaNew;
}

int * concatenate(int aa[], int sizeAA, int bb[], int sizeBB)   /*This 
function takes in two different arrays, creates a new array, then copies 
both arrays into the new array.It returns a pointer to the new array*/
{
    //Create new array size
    int newSize = (sizeAA + sizeBB);

    //Create new array
    int* concatArray;
    concatArray = new int[newSize];

    //Add elements of first and second array into new array
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
    {
        if (i >= 0 && i < sizeAA)       //Check to see if a value from the first or second array is supposed to be added
            concatArray[i] = aa[i];
        else
            concatArray[i] = bb[i - sizeAA];
    }

    return concatArray;
}

int * subArray(int a[], int start, int length)    /* This function takes in 
an array, a start value, and a length value. It creates a new array and 
copies the values of the original array starting at the passed start value 
and continues until the new array is the length of the passed length value. 
It returns a pointer to the new array*/
{
    //Create new array size
    int subSize = length;

    //Create a new array
    int* sub;
    sub = new int[subSize];

    //Add elements of original array starting at the passed start value into new 
    array until the new array is the length specified by the argument
    for (int i = 0; i < subSize; i++)
    {
        sub[i] = a[start];
        start += 1;
    }

    return sub;
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would probably be the correct site on which to post a question like this one

Comment: Got it, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Your set up is very good. Glad to see you're getting the hang of it. Your functions could use some optimization, however. Before we begin, Id 'd like to note that C++ has a `std::vector` class which dynamically allocates memory as needed and supplies many powerful mod functions. I'd recommend checking that out as it would take your program to the next level. 
To begin, Your `Expand()`function is pretty well set up. Just some minor modifications: to clean up your code,

```
int* aaNew;
int newSize = size * 2;
aaNew = new int[newSize];
```

can simply become:

```
int newSize = size * 2;
int *aaNew = new int[newSize];
```

and within your `for` loop, there is no need to check the complete range of `i`, only its upper bound:

```
if (i >= 0 && i < size)
```

can become:

```
if (i < size)
```

This will have the same result as your `if-statement` but is more elegant since `i` will never be less than 0.

Moving on, your `concatenate()` function could become a lot simpler. While what you are doing is technically correct and works, your `concatenate()` function could simplify to:

```
int * concatenate(int aa[], int sizeAA, int bb[], int sizeBB) {

    int * result = new int[sizeAA + sizeBB];
    copy(aa, aa + sizeAA, result);
    copy(bb, bb + sizeBB, result + sizeAA);
    return result;

}
```

Furthermore, in your `subArray()` function, you can reduce:

```
//Create new array size
int subSize = length;

//Create a new array
int* sub;
sub = new int[subSize];
```

to:

```
//Create new array size
int subSize = length;
int *sub = new int[subSize];
```

Lastly, your main function could use an overhaul. Consider adding a `writeArray()` function since you are repeating that task often:

```
string writeArray(int ar[], int arLength) {
    string ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arLength; i++)
        ret += " " + to_string(i);
    return ret + "\n";
}
```

That way your `main()` can become:

```
int main() {

    //Declare variables
    const int SIZEAA = 10, SIZEBB = 5;
    int aa[SIZEAA] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
    int bb[SIZEBB] = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55 };

    //Output both original arrays
    cout << "aa[10]: " << writeArray(aa, SIZEAA);
    cout << "bb[5]: " << writeArray(bb, SIZEBB);

    //Call the Expand function
    int *aaExpand = Expand(aa, SIZEAA);
    cout << "Testing Expand: " << writeArray(aaExpand, SIZEAA * 2);

    //Call the concatenate function
    int *concatenateArray = concatenate(aa, SIZEAA, bb, SIZEBB);
    cout << "Testing concatenate: " << writeArray(concatenateArray,
                                                 (SIZEAA + SIZEBB));

    //Call subArray function
    int *arraySub = subArray(aa, 5, 4);
    cout << "Testing subArray: " << writeArray(arraySub, 4);
    //Output the sub array

    //Release dynamic memory
    delete[] aaExpand;
    delete[] concatenateArray;
    delete[] arraySub;

    aaExpand = nullptr;
    concatenateArray = nullptr;
    arraySub = nullptr;

}
```

The rest of your program looks decent. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Good to mention `std::vector`, but there is educational value in `new/delete` (not to mention you retaining control of memory allocation). So good to mention the higher level data handling classes, but always encourage a full understanding of all aspects of the language.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin for the tip. I was goin for that!!

Comment: You got it, it was just a little unclear whether that was a push to vector and away from `new/delete`, or a mention that more "good things are to come". Really good effort on the answer!

Comment: @David With `std::vector` you retain control of allocations equally well. There's just no explicit `new`/`delete` and surrounding boilerplate code.

Answer (score -1):

```
    int* Expand(int elements[], int size)
    {
        int* new_elements = new int[2 * size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            new_elements[i] = elements[i];
            new_elements[i + size] = -1;
        }

        return new_elements;
    }

    int* concatenate(int first[], int firstSize, int second[], int secondSize)
    {
        int* elements = new int[firstSize + secondSize];

        for (int i = 0; i < firstSize; i++)
        {
            elements[i] = first[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; i < secondSize; j++)
        {
            elements[firstSize + j] = second[j];
        }

        return elements;
    }

    int* subArray(int elements[], int offset, int size)
    {
        int* new_elements = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            new_elements[i] = elements[offset + i];
        }

        return new_elements;
    }
```

Comment: An answer that just shows code with no explanation about why it is an answer is not much of a useful answer.